# Get form-data in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, form-data, body-parser

I have an app on nodejs and I already get the requests in json format (No issue here).

The problem comes when I want to upload a video through form-data. Here is a little bit of my code:

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
require('./routes/routes')(app);
```

Routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app){
app.post('/save', ensureAuthenticated, activity.publish); //JSON REQUEST
app.post('/video', ensureAuthenticated, activity.video); //FORM-DATA REQUEST
}
```

I try to use express-formidable (in Server.js) but it breaks my '/save' route. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I advice you to use multer

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Example:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})

app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})

var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }])
app.post('/cool-profile', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is an object (String -> Array) where fieldname is the key, and the value is array of files
  //
  // e.g.
  //  req.files['avatar'][0] -> File
  //  req.files['gallery'] -> Array
  //
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have one question: Multer needs to work as a middleware? because I already have one and I want to keep it.

Comment: Yes, but you can use several middleware

Comment: Did you like my answer? If so, rate it.